# Jquery find is not working

Tags: jquery, find

This is the Html for my page I just want if there are no popular products then the whole div popular_prd should hide.

```
<div class="popular_prd">
    <h1 class="views-heading">Popular Products</h1>
    <div class="view view-popular-products view-id-popular_products view-display-id-default boxes-bottom view-dom-id-3">
        <div class="views-admin-links views-hide">
            <ul class="links">
                <li class="0 first">
                    <a href="/admin/build/views/edit/popular_products?destination=node#views-tab-default">Edit</a>
                </li>
                <li class="1">
                    <a href="/admin/build/views/export/popular_products">Export</a>
                </li>
                <li class="2 last">
                    <a href="/admin/build/views/clone/popular_products">Clone</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the following jquery code to hide tthe div.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
if(!$('.popular_prd').find('.view-content') ) {
        $('.popular_prd').hide();
    }
    else {
    $('.popular_prd').show();
    }
});
```

But the code is not working the div is still showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` doesn't work the way you think.  It looks like instead of

```
if(!$('.popular_prd').find('.view-content') ) {
```

what you mean is

```
if(!$('.popular_prd').find('.view-content').length ) {
```

In fact, you don't even need `find` here...

```
if(!$('.popular_prd .view-content').length ) {
```

Bottom line, jQuery selectors don't return true or false, but a set.  Test the `length` to see whether anything was found.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.popular_prd').find('.view-content')
```

This will just return a jQuery object which never evaluates to false

You need to check the length of it

```
if(!$('.popular_prd').find('.view-content').length) {
  //no products.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `length` property

```
$('document').ready(function(){
if(!$('.popular_prd').find('.view-content').length) {
        $('.popular_prd').hide();
    }
    else {
    $('.popular_prd').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a view-content class in your HTML.

Comment: That's probably the point of the question. 'It's not there, so how do I check for it?'

Answer (score -1):

`view-content` class is not contained in the div with class `popular_prd` in the above `HTML`

Comment: That's probably the point of the question. 'It's not there, so how do I check for it?'

Comment: Its example for Class name.